# Code & Variables For New Tumblr Pop-Up Share Box

Tags: variables, popup, themes, share, tumblr

Has anyone figured out the exact code and styling for the new drop down/pop up share box that comes with the new default tumblr theme? (this one: http://www.tumblr.com/theme/37310 )
It comes with:
 "Share to twitter",
 "Share to facebook",
  "permalink", 
and when on safari for iPad or google for android it shows 
"Open in app".
 The new like and reblog buttons are shown in tumblr theme docs but not the drop down share menu 
It looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ7PE.jpg

I would like to start adding the box to the themes I use. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. There isn't a theme variable or block of code to create the pop up menu, its custom. You would have to recreate it yourself.

Comment: Hi again Mike, grateful for your help as usual. Yeah, I had kind of figured it may be something like this,couldn't see any stylesheets associated with them to access. I copied what I thought was the basics and browsers interpret it as this: http://i.imgur.com/G2IqECF.jpg?1 and it works but needs styling. Should I be able to do that? Are you adding any to your themes? I would like to see what professionals are doing (not to copy!! Just trying to learn from you!! (⊙﹏⊙) ) with regards to these changes. I did add the new like & reblog buttons, at least they work!

Comment: Hey! Yeah I think its fine recreating it. However, I can see the benefit of having something to *copy and paste*. Leave it with me I will try and recreate the menu so others can drop it in, so to speak.